# Devise new user password and edit user password Redirect to many times, can't go through Forgot password

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5

The links are straightforward

```
<%= link_to 'new_user_password', new_user_password_path %>
<%= link_to 'edit_user_password', edit_user_password_path %>
```

the routes are:

```
devise_for :users
```

and I've tried with:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:passwords => 'passwords'}
```

Inheriting the Devise::Passwords controller in the passwords controller. But I can't seem to get past the redirects.

I have:

```
before_action :sanitize_devise_params, if: :devise_controller?
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
before_action :set_auth

def sanitize_devise_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :privacy, :organization])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username, :privacy, :organization])
end

def configure_permitted_parameters
    update_attrs = [:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: update_attrs
end

def set_auth
    @auth = session[:omniauth] if session[:omniauth]
end
```

I can't tell where else there might be a fault that would cause this to break like this.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to clear the cookies